# What does it mean to substitute $y = x''$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The textbook I'm reading says this for this problem:

$$x^2y''+2xy' − 2y=0.$$

> Since differentiating a power pushes down the exponent by one unit,
>   the form of this equation suggests that we look for possible solutions
>   of the type $y=x''$. On substituting this in the differential equation
>   and dividing by the common factor $x''$, we obtain the quadratic
>   equation $n(n − 1)+2n − 2=0$

What do they mean by this substitution, taking it like a literal substitution gives this nonsense which I obviously can't divide out the common factor $x''$

Literal substiution gives $$x^2(x'')'' + 2x(x'')' -2(x'') = 0$$

I can't divide everything by $x''$ because not everything is being multiplied by $x''$, for example, $(x'')''$ is the second derivative of $x''$ so I can't factor out $x''$ from that. What does the author mean by substituting $y=x''$, how did he end up with a quadratic?

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't “solutions of the type $y=x^n$” ?

Comment: It's a typo. The intended "Ansatz"  is $y:=x^n$. This immediately leads to the quoted equation.

Comment: Substituting $y=x^n$ means you have to solve: $$x^2 (x^n)''+2x(x^n)'-2x^n=0$$

Comment: @MartinR The quote is directly from the pdf, I screenshotted as well, I guess it's a typo?

Comment: That must be a typo, as pointed out in the above comments. The “common factor” is $x^n$ as well.

Comment: what's is the title of the book ?

Comment: Try searching Cauchy-Euler ODE, it must be $y=x^m$ so its the same if you use $y=x''=x^m$ I guess

Comment: @MRASSASSINS117 "so its the same if you use..." Wrong guess, it is not "the same", it is absurd.

Comment: According to the discussion as https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28615/42969, this question is **on-topic.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a typographical error in the book. Both occurrences of $x''$ should
be $x^n$.

$x$ is the independent variable, so $y = x''$ is the zero function, i.e.
the trivial solution of the differential equation.

With $y = x^n$ everything falls into place: $y' = n x^{n-1}$,
$y = n(n-1) x^{n-2}$, and substitution into the differential equation 
gives
$$
n(n − 1)x^n +2nx^n − 2x^n=0 
$$
so that the common factor $x^n$ can be divided out:
$$
n(n − 1)+2n − 2=0 \, .
$$

*Remark:* From a Google search is seems that the quote is from
[Differential Equations with Applications and Historical Notes, Third Edition, by George F. Simmons](https://books.google.de/books?id=hNi_DQAAQBAJ&pg=PR71&lpg=PR71&dq=Since+differentiating+a+power+pushes+down+the+exponent+by+one+unit,+the+form+of+this+equation+suggests+that+we+look+for+possible+solutions+of+the+type&source=bl&ots=xqxjyFqQ4s&sig=PNXtF8Q_VMoz1WXspoBIgz84cSk&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJuNSQ14zcAhUJJJoKHQ3XBi8Q6AEISjAK#v=onepage&q=Since%20differentiating%20a%20power%20pushes%20down%20the%20exponent%20by%20one%20unit%2C%20the%20form%20of%20this%20equation%20suggests%20that%20we%20look%20for%20possible%20solutions%20of%20the%20type&f=false), which really has that typographical error.